# How to change the values from the accelerometer

Tags: javascript, java, android

at the accelerometer the values ​​start at 0 degree and go to +180 -180 degrees.
How can I do that the value start at 90 degree and left and right goes down to 0 degree.

```js
if (mags != null && accels != null) {
                gravity = new float[9];
                magnetic = new float[9];
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(gravity, magnetic, accels, mags);
                float[] outGravity = new float[9];
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(gravity, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outGravity);
                SensorManager.getOrientation(outGravity, values);

                roll = values[2] ;
                mags = null;
                accels = null;
                double degree = Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(roll));

                if (degree < 0) {

                    degree *= -1;
                    zValue.setText(Math.round(degree) + "°");

                }

                    else {

                    zValue.setText(Math.round(degree) + "°");
                }

            }


        }
    };
}
```

Comment: -180 and +180 degrees are two different values, are you sure you want two different values to yield the same value i.e. 0 ?

Comment: Why did you use the javascript tag?

Comment: I added my code. If I tilt my phone left or right the value goes from 0 to 180 degree. For my app i need that the value would have to start at 90 ° and go to 0 °. my englisch is not so good sry :/

Comment: is this tag wrong f1sh?

Comment: @MichaelBrilz yes, javascript is something very different than java.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int newValue = 90 - (Math.abs(oldValue)/2);
```

For an oldValue of -180, this returns 0. For an oldValue of 0, this returns 90.